# AsyncFileUpload upload complete not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using ajaxToolkit:AsyncFileUpload in my asp.net application. In AsyncFileUpload1_UploadedComplete server side event, I am trying to make a label visible and change it text but button is not being enabled.

I am using client side event of the asyncfileupload control as well like this:

```
function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
    var filename = args.get_fileName();
    var contentType = args.get_contentType();
    var text = "Size of " + filename + " is " + args.get_length() + " bytes";
    if (contentType.length > 0) {
        text += " and content type is '" + contentType + "'.";
    }
    document.getElementById('<%= lblStatus.ClientID %>').innerText = text;
}
```

All label, button and file upload controls are outside updatepanel. I tried putting controls inside updatepanel as well but same result.

Pleas suggest solution

Answer (score 2):

It is Asyncfileupload. It works asynchronously. So you send files to codebehind. And it turns you result. No viewstate, no postback, no html rendering.

So you can't change label or button. If you want this, use normal fileupload. Or do your jobs on client side..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem once .. You can not set visible to true or false but you can set its style .. Here is what I did ..

```
function OnClientAsyncFileUploadComplete(sender, args) {            
        //similar to visible = false;
        document.getElementById('<%=lbl_Lable1.ClientID%>').style.display = 'none'; 

        //similar to visible = true;
        document.getElementById('<%=lbl_Lable2.ClientID%>').style.display = 'inline';

        return true;
    }
```

I am sorry I wont be of much help on setting text in label as I had predefined text in label but you can always merge your innertext or innerhtml code with it ..